# Raspberry pi network over usb

Tags: networking, usb

Hi I am very new to the Raspberry pi but I have experience with the beaglebone.

I am just wondering if its possible to do something like network-over-USB like on beaglebone , but for the raspberry pi using the micro usb power connector. Since it would be much easier to connect to SSH and power up the board in one go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about beaglebone, but it is possible to network the Pi using ssh or VNC.
ssh used to require configuration in raspi-config, but I believe is now on by default.
VNC requires installation

`sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`

You can't use the micro USB connector as the data is not connected (only power pins).

Answer (score 1):

The Pi's power connector is power-only, so it can't be used for networking purposes.  A couple other things to try:

1. Set up the Pi to connect to a hotspot created by (say) an Android phone, connect your laptop as well, then ssh over the phone's local network.  This is how I used my Pi headless for quite a while.
2. Connect an ethernet cable directly between your pi and your laptop.  (The Pi automatically detects if it's connected directly to a computer, and plays nice if it is!)  You'll need to configure both the Pi and the laptop to use a static IP address over the ethernet network, but then you can SSH over the ethernet cable quite easily.